# VBA - Check if cell value is in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets on Excel.

Sheet 1 contains a list of ~500 universities, with their global rankings in column A and university names in column B

Sheet 2 contains a list of individuals' names in column A, their university in column B and their exam scores in column C.

I would like to write a VBA code that checks sheet 2 if the individual's university is in the top 50 rank (in sheet 1, row 1 to row 50). If it is, I will multiply their score in column C by 1.15.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: MCVE is the abbreviation for a **M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample - [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). SO expects a new question not only to include the desired behaviour, but that you describe the **core problem** or error you are confronted with by showing typically the *shortest code* - even pseudo code -  with *all* necessary parts (Complete) to reproduce the issue (Verifiable). 
Please edit your question to provide that information as otherwise you risk to get no answers or to get down voted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (i did not check in live)

```
Sub checkUniversity()
Dim shInd As Worksheet
Dim rgInd As Range


Set shInd = Worksheets("Individuals")  ' put here name of your sheet

rgInd = shInd.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
lastR = rgInd.Rows.Count

With shInd
    For j = 2 To lastR ' assuming that row1 is header, and data starts in row2
    
        .Cells(j, 3).Value = .Cells(j, 3).Value * isTop50(.Cells(j, 2).Value)
    Next j
End With
End Sub

Function isTop50(university As String)
Dim shUniver As Worksheet
Set shUniver = Worksheets("universities")  'put here name of your sheet with universities
isTop50 = 1

For i = 2 To 51  '('2 is first row - 1st university, 51 row of 50th university)
    If shUniver.Cells(i, 2).Value = university Then
        isTop50 = 1.15
        Exit Function
    End If
Next i
End Function
```

after short time:
why you want to do this with vba while you just have normal funcitons which you can use in eg column D of sheet individuals

```
=if(isna(vlookup(B2, [sheetUniversities]!B2:B51,1,0)), C2, C2*1.15)
```